# How to create multiple objects with django transactions?

Tags: python, django, django-models, transactions

I have to retrieve M objects from a list of Q objects and then maps the M objects to an User. To achieve this, I need to run the code inside a transaction and roll back the DB in the case 1 of M objects are not created:

```
def polls(request, template_name='polls/polls.html'):
    question_list = random.sample(list(Question.objects.all()), 3)
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            for question in question_list:
                UserToQuestion.objects.create(
                    user=request.user.id,
                    question=question.id
                )
    except IntegrityError:
        handle_exception()
```

How I can achieve this? How the exception should be handled? The django documentation doesn't show a real example.

Is also possible perform this task during the user registration overriding the save method in way each registered user is mapped to N questions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [django signals](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html) while doing user registration.
Also you do not need  `with transaction.atomic():` part. You need to use 
[bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: I added your suggestion and edited the question, but the signal is not triggered

Comment: find a working code on internet or github then look you are not doing right.

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/ktdb3g/django-signals-an-extremely-simplified-explanation-for-beginners

Comment: Actually I directed you signals and bulk create and it will kind to choose mine to as an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, we create a signal, in order to map the related questions to an user when the user is registered. The signal is triggered from post_save() and the call-back function retrieve N random questions and map it to the user. The signal must be connected, to do it, we use the decorator @receiver. We also need to use a transaction, cause of bulk_create() method.

## signals.py

```
import random

from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from polls.models import Question, UserToQuestion


@transaction.atomic
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def sig_user_registered(instance, **kwargs):
    question_list = random.sample(list(Question.objects.all()), 3)
    UserToQuestion.objects.bulk_create([
        UserToQuestion(user=instance, question=question) for question in question_list
    ])
```

The signal must be imported. To do it, we use the method ready().

## apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class AccountConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'account'

    def ready(self):
        import account.signals
```

Finally, we load the application

## settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps
    # ...
    # Third-party apps
    # ...
    # Your apps
    'account.apps.AccountConfig',
    # ...
]
```